# Oracle databases loop tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle database and I am running the below query

```
select table_name
from db_test.test
where table_name like '%20170128'
```

This returns me a column with all the tables with the specific date at the end.
How can I take this list and query them?

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL -- think `execute immediate`.

Comment: As an aside, I'd point out that if you have incorporated dates into your table names, then you have a severe design flaw in your system.  Instead of creating different tables just to hold different dates worth of data, you should have a single table with a DATE column to distinguish the data by date.

Comment: I get your point, you are totally correct in hive I have partitioned by date. Although the table in the oracle is like this : id_code_date and store records for each date for a specific id_code. Thanks a lot for this point of view.

Comment: It might be easiest to create a view dynamically and then query that however you want. Years ago (before partitioning) I saw a system that rebuilt a view of the last 30 days' date-specific tables (using `union all`) every night as a batch job. Would something like that work?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson can you please post a url with this example to investigate it further? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: There's no URL - this was a system at a telco where I worked in the mid 90s. Partitioning didn't exist so instead they had a table for each day, and every night they rebuilt a view that was a UNION ALL of all the tables for individual dates. Then you could `select * from v_calls_last_30_days where call_date = date '2021-04-21'`. I could probably work up a demo, though your example suggests you need to go back 4 years so this may not be practical for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need dynamic SQL.  If you're running a simple query against each table (I'm just doing a `count(*)` in this example), something like this would work

```
declare
  l_cnt integer;
  l_sql varchar2(1000);
begin 
  for t in (select table_name
              from db_test.test
             where table_name like '%20170128')
  loop
    l_sql := 'select count(*) from ' || t.table_name;
    execute immediate l_sql
                 into l_cnt;
    dbms_output.put_line( t.table_name || ' has ' || l_cnt || ' rows.' );
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I want to select * . Is it possible please to explain me the logic?

Comment: @DrGenius - What are you going to do with the results?  If you're going to do an `execute immediate`, you'd need to have somewhere to put the results which would require that you know the structure of the results in advance.  Generally, that's not possible if you're building a query at runtime but maybe all the tables in your system have a fixed structure.

Comment: The structure is fixed. I want to fetch with sqoop data from oracle db into hive. But instead of every time write the table name I want to make it more automatic.

Comment: @DrGenius - OK.  So every table that query returns has the identical structure?  Having table names with dates embedded in them and having a bunch of tables with the same structure seems a really weird way to structure a database.  In the loop, you could fetch the data into a local collection defined to match the structure of the table.  But if the goal is to return the data to a client application, this seems like a fundamentally poor approach.